# What's the meaning of vnode in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

I notice that vnode can be migrated between different node, it looks like that the vnode is the data stored in the nodes, but I can't find any description in the docs of the cnosdb.

it just say in the separation mode.

```
Vnode is a virtual running unit and is distributed to a specific Node. Each Vnode is a separate LSM Tree. Its corresponding tsfamily structure is a separate running unit.
```